# How to add images in CSS file? I am using python flask for website development

Tags: python, html, css, image, flask

Everything was working fine before Python Flask. Now I tried to connect my HTML page with Python Flask. CSS is working fine but when I define images inside the CSS file the image is no longer loaded into the web site. Instead it is showing error 404.

python app.py code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__ , static_url_path='/static')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('/intro.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML code :-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>NewliFit</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/owl.carousel.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/owl.carousel.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = 'css/owl.theme.default.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/firstone.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="cover-image">
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="leftmenu">
```

CSS file

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

*{
    margin: 0px ;
    padding: 0px ;
}
/* ------------cover image -------------*/
.cover-image {
    background-image: url({{ url_for('static',filename = '/images/cover4.jpg')}});
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110vh;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: First of all you do need `static_url_path='/static'` while this is the default static folder. Secondly change to `background: url("/static/images/cover.jpg")` I hope your static folder is under your root folder of project and css folder inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using url_for in a CSS file, which does not work. You need to specify the url of the background image either in the HTML file, or specify a proper URL in your CSS.

So either add this to your CSS:

```
background-image: url('/static/images/cover4.jpg')}});
```

Or change your cover-image div in your HTML file to this:

```
<div class="cover-image" style="background-image: url({{ url_for('static',filename = '/images/cover4.jpg')}});">
```

Unless you plan on changing your static folder (or your cover image) regularly, I would advise going the first route, to make sure you separate style and semantics.

Answer (score 0):

None of the methods really work. I tried displacing the slashes, using url_for method to embed the images in the external stylesheet with background-image. But url_for method doesn't work, neither does the direct file path.

The best solution I found for this problem is adding the explicit property within the html file using either internal or inline style methods.

Eg.1. Internal style (Add it in your head of html along with your external stylesheet.)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/your-external-stylesheet.css') }}" type="text/css">
        <style>
            body  {
                background-image: url("{{ url_for('static', filename='images/your-image-here.jpg') }}");
            }
        </style>
    </head>
</html>
```

Eg.2. Inline style (Add it to your explicit segment)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/your-external-stylesheet.css') }}" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body style="background-image: url("{{ url_for('static', filename='css/your-external-stylesheet.css') }}");>
        Your body here
    </body>
</html>
```